# iPad IOS5 orientation

Tags: ipad

I am currently working on an application on the iPad. It only supports the portrait orientation but not the landscape. What code (what file) should be edited or added in the .m file in order to make it support the landscape left? I need all the pages in the app to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Every UIViewController needs to implement this method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to support only a few (Just return NO on whatever you don't wish to be supported):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    //Allow Original Portrait
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    //Allow Upside Down
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    //Allow Landscape Left
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    //Allow Landscape Right
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you are indeed correct, I assumed from the question that he may have merely wanted to support everything...Just edited the answer to support anything, with a very easy way to not support a particular orientation if desired... @H2CO3

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Looks like just the upside down orientation works when I use this in the code. How do I make it work for landscape left and right?

Comment: This code needs to be in your root view controller (whatever view controller is on top)...its initially set in your appDelegate file with the line: self.window = someViewController; (someViewController is your root view controller) @user1464107

Comment: Thant helped.Thank you. The next problem I see is that when the screen rotates, the dimentions are not right (frame size). Can you suggest me what I can do with this?

Answer (score 0):

In each view controller you'll need to add the following code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {    
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOritentationPortraitUpsideDown));
 }
```

Comment: However, I believe Apple **strongly** suggests allowing all orientations in iPad Apps. So unless you have a good reason to not support landscape your might have the app rejected.